# Replace excel cell value if cell contains text and don't replace text If it is empty

Tags: python

I have a requirement that replaces excel cell value(string/text) with "X" and doesn't replace it if it is empty.

Comment: Provide the sample data as now it doesn't explain much. Is this question really related to Python?

Comment: Using Python script replace excel cell value with "X" if it contains string/text

Comment: There is little information in your question. From what I am reading: If an Excel condition doesn't work, because I need to modify exactly the same cell, I would use a VBA.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Given that no use case or details are provided, see if this is what you want.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value != None:
            cell.value = 'X'
            
wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Solution is worked! Thank you ytung-dev!